# Finding k-nn with LSH when k > size of bucket

Tags: database, postgresql, computer-science, nearest-neighbor, locality-sensitive-hash

I've been reading up on the literature around locality sensitive hashing, and I think have a pretty good understanding of how it works. Considering the most simple case of a single hash table where each document is in only one bucket, my question is:

**How do I find k nearest neighbours where k is greater than the number of documents in that bucket?**

I've seen several methods to accomplish this. Some use a [prefix tree](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~bawa/Pub/similarity.pdf). Others sort all the buckets by their [hamming distance](https://github.com/eulerto/pg_similarity).

My constraints:

I have my document IDs stored in **PostgreSQL** alongside their respective buckets. A **full table scan** to calculate the hamming distance with each bucket is **not feasible** (I have **hundreds of millions of documents**). My bucket hash will likely be **24, or 32 bits** (unless there is a suggestion against this). Does anyone have experience with, or suggested approaches on how to proceed?